# failed compile from test_helper

Tags: testing, reactjs, mocha.js, chai

i wrote test_helper for testing my react components but every time i hit `npm start` and following errors come out.

```
> jsonplaceholder-client@0.0.1 test /Users/WOOJUNG/Desktop/jsonplaceholder-client
> mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test

/Users/WOOJUNG/Desktop/jsonplaceholder-client/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:573
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /Users/WOOJUNG/Desktop/jsonplaceholder-client/test/test_helper.js: Unexpected token (21:4)
  19 | function renderComponent(ComponentClass, props = {}, state = {}) {
  20 |   const componentInstance =  TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
> 21 |     <Provider store={createStore(reducers, state)}>
     |     ^
  22 |       <ComponentClass {...props} />
  23 |     </Provider>
  24 |   );
```

it seems like error occurs because of failed compile `test_helper`. I'm not sure but as I know `js:babel-core/register` can compile es6 but it fails. should I give another options to compile `test_helper`? but I have no idea. T_ T

Comment: Can you include your `.babelrc` file?

Comment: @MichaelParker thanks a lot I forgot `.babelrc` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either have your **.babelrc** config in your **package.json** file as below

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"]
  }
}
```

OR

Make sure you have you **.babelrc** in the root if your app folder. Same level as other config. files

My **.babelrc** looks like,

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"]
}
```